# How to upload an image in firebase version 9?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to update the version 8 code to version 9, but the image that is uploaded yields `Error loading preview` ...

Here is the code:

```js
async storeImage(img: { uri: string; base64: string }, userId: string) {
    try {
      let imageUrl = null;
      const imageName = img.uri.substring(img.uri.length - 40);

      const imageRef = ref(this.storage, `profile-images/${userId}/${imageName}`);


      uploadString(imageRef, img.base64, 'base64', { contentType: "image/jpg" }).then((snapshot) => {
        console.log("image stored", snapshot);
      })

      getDownloadURL(ref(this.storage, `profile-images/${userId}/${imageName}`))
        .then(url => {
          const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.responseType = 'blob';
          xhr.onload = (event) => {
            const blob = xhr.response;
          };
          xhr.open('GET', url);
          xhr.send();
          console.log('getDownloadURL', url);

          imageUrl = url;
        })

      return imageUrl
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

The `uri` string is the address on the device, the `base64` is
`/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAgESAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAJgAAAAAAA6ABAAMAAAABAAEAAKACAAQAAAABAAAAyKADAAQAAAABAAAAhAAAAAD/7QA4UGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAAA4QklNBCUAAAAAABDUHYzZjwCyBOmACZ...`

[This](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/en-touto-nika.appspot.com/o/profile-images%2F5E5hc3oOCJRYM4RByLf7ORTIP103%2F00474A96-87BE-441E-9975-E03689942B82.jpg?alt=media&token=4b8a617a-e506-42de-ae48-be0d7a57f7cf) is the url from the firebase storage preview.

This is the downloaded [url](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp.appspot.com/o/profile-images%2F5E5hc3oOCJRYM4RByLf7ORTIP103%2FFABA27E8-2C87-42F4-9B17-9C57AB212E23.jpg?alt=media&token=9bb40cbf-63fa-4051-bcc4-5d8d0f15aaad), which should be the same as the above.

I tried also in `uploadString` to use `base64url` but nothing.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you see/open the uploaded image in the Firebase console? PS: The `ref()` method is not asynchronous, so no need to use await.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec The `This` in the above sentence `This is the url from the firebase storage preview.` is the link to the uploaded image. When I try to preview, it says `Error loading preview`.

Comment: Are you sure you pass a correctly base64 encoded image?

Comment: Yes, it's valid! I just checked it [here](https://base64.guru/tools/validator)